# Can't understand the proof of worst time complexity in Algorithms P146

Tags: algorithm, math

On page 146 in `Algorithms Fourth Edition`, a proof of the worst time complexity of quick-union algorithm is given. It says

> Let's assume the height of a tree which has i nodes has the maximum height 
>   of log(i).
>
> Given i + j = k, i <= j, when the tree of i and j nodes are unioned, the 
>   height of the tree = 1 + log(i) = log(i + i) <= log(i + j) = log(k).

I can't understand why `1 + log(i) = log(i + i)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `log(i + i) = log(2i) = log(2) + log(i)` and as `log(2) = 1`, we can say `log(i + i) = 1 + log(i)`.